# Eclipse plugin for python to give different indentation levels different colors

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

What I'm looking for is an eclipse extension to work with PyDev to make different levels of indentation have different colored indentations before it. For example, reference the code block below

```
1     for line in list:
2         function.dothing()
3         if condition:
4             do something
```

The plugin I'm looking for, if it exists, would color the spaces between `1` and `for` one color (say, red), and then the spaces between the numbers and text on lines 2/3 a different color (say, green), and the spaces between `4` and `do` yet another color (say, blue). Does anything like this exist, if yes, what's it called?

(Bad) graphical representation:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Eclipse have indentation guides?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000219/does-eclipse-have-indentation-guides)

Comment: After looking at that thread and playing with editbox, I have to disagree @aruisdante. Editbox doesn't provide the exact functionality I'm looking for

Comment: There were many other suggestions in that thread. I linked it as a duplicate because it's asking the same question. Unless you're asking for horizontal lines without changing the background (essentially an underline), which I don't think Eclipse's text editors themselves support (or at least I've never seen them)

Comment: I'm thinking something like this: http://imgur.com/RFv5Ep0

Comment: EditBox's color-levels option seems to be like that.

Comment: It seems to be, but what it does is it colors the entire indentation-level box, whereas I only want the space *before* the line to be colored

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such an option right now. Currently the closer you can get is EditBox: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/EditBox

Not sure, but it may be something that could be added as an option to EditBox if you're up to changing its code...